# Does it make sense to study a Hidden Markov Model with an identity transition matrix?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

Let's say I have a huge number of samples describing relatively long sequences of a high number of observable states, but whose 2 possible hidden states are constant inside a sequence.

(Practically, these samples are sequences of Windows API calls, which are the observed states, from malware and benign software, those two classes being the hidden states, and the objective being to determine which behavior is exhibited by new sequences)

Another way of saying this is that the transition matrix is a 2x2 identity matrix since the hidden states never change.

Does it make sense to train a HMM with an identity transition matrix ?

(Bonus question : can you think of a better way to approach the practical problem using HMMs ?)

Comment: Wouldn't an identity transistion matrix imply that the chain remains forever in the state that it started? As a model that doesn't make much sense ...

Answer (score 2):

The identity transition matrix means the state can never change. What you’ve turned this into is a restricted kind of naive Bayes model over sequences, where each position in the sequence is independent given the class.

---

#### Comparison to HMM

Your model’s generative story is this:

> Sample a class $c$.
>
> for i in 1…n:
>
> > Sample an observation $x_i$ given $c$

Note the difference from the HMM generative story; you’ve pushed $c$ out of the loop.

> for i in 1…n:
>
> > Sample a class $c_i$ given $c_{i-1}$
> >
> > Sample an observation $x_i$ given $c_i$

---

#### Improving on this

You can think of your identity-based model as a **mixture of 0th-order Markov chains**. That is, each observation doesn’t even depend on the previous observation—the usual Markov assumption!

This suggests an easy improvement on the model: use a higher order Markov chain. Instead of having $x_i$ depend only on the class, you can have it depend on the previous observation—or maybe the previous two or three! (Reminder: your observations are which API calls are made.)

---

#### A connection: language identification (for your bonus question)

In natural language processing, n-gram language models are just nth-order Markov models over (e.g.) words. You may want to identify the (unknown) language of text with these models. It becomes a case of statistical inference. You can use that exact inference procedure to identify whether your computer is in a malware state.

> Is the text I see Polish or Spanish?

> Is my sequence of API calls malware or benign?

Train one Markov chain on only Polish and one on only Spanish. Choose a prior probability for each category.

Your model is now $p(c \mid \vec{x}) \propto p(\vec{x}  \mid c) p(c)$—a noisy channel model defined by Bayes’s rule. The first term is your Markov model, and the second is your prior belief. Using the resulting probabilities, you can make a decision about whether your program is malware.

**Reminder:** Your identity transition HMM is a special case of what I just described!